# Pattern / best practice for accessing connection that has undeterministic set time

Tags: java, design-patterns

Below code attempts to get a connection every 5 seconds. The getConnection method returns true or false depending on random double and is
for illustrative purposes. The time it takes to get a connection cannot be guaranteed so if fail to initially get connection, wait 5 seconds
and try again. Once the connection is attained, then just exit.

Is there better/cleaner method of getting the connection instead of using if statements and Thread.sleep ? It seems wrong (im not sure why) sleeping the running thread for 5 seconds before trying again.

```
public class TestAlive {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        while (true) {
            try {
                if (getConnection()) {
                    System.out.println("Got connection, do some work.....");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("No connection, re-trying in 5 seconds");
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Boolean getConnection() {
        return Math.random() > 0.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: I came across this post while looking answer to your question. It looks like a similar problem and a solution with good design.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692595/design-pattern-for-retrying-logic-that-failed

Hope it helps.

Comment: It looks fine but make sure to propagate interruption vs. swallowing the interuptedexception (unless you have a good reason not to)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a loop with a `Thread.sleep` is a good approach, especially if you want to include a maximum number of retries and since rethrowing the `InterruptedException` is most likely the best way to handle interrupts in a situation like this.

An alternative would be to use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) as follows:

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

exec.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
    if (getConnection()) {
        System.out.println("Got connection, do some work.....");
        System.exit(0);  // Or exec.shutdown();
    } else {
        System.out.println("No connection, re-trying in 5 seconds");
    }
}, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

or using `Timer`:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        if (getConnection()) {
            System.out.println("Got connection, do some work.....");
            System.exit(0);  // And/or timer.cancel()
        } else {
            System.out.println("No connection, re-trying in 5 seconds");
        }
    }
}, new Date(), 5000);
```

If this pattern is used in several places, I'd suggest creating a wrapper that accepts a `Runnable` (or even better, `Callable`).

On a related note, this is the exact code I use in one of my projects:

```
int attempt = 0;
while (true) {
    Log.info("Trying to connect. Attempt " + (++attempt) + " of " + MAX_CONNECT_ATTEMPTS);
    try {
        return makeConnectionAttempt();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.error("Connection attempt failed: " + ex.getMessage());
        if (attempt >= MAX_CONNECT_ATTEMPTS) {
            Log.error("Giving up");
            throw new IOException("Could not connect to server", ex);
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(WAIT_BETWEEN_CONNECT_ATTEMPTS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think call `Thread.sleep(5000)` is wrong in this case, but maybe dangerous in a bigger application, for this purposes, I use [CronTriggers](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) of [QuartzScheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation) and work really smooth.

A CronTrigger with declaration `0/5 * * * * ?` will be executed 5 seconds after last triggered process finishes. But there are plenty of configurations applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Thread.sleep()` is [bad practise](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/sleep_issues.shtml)

use `Timer` instead

```
timer = new Timer();

if (timer != null) {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                if (getConnection()) {
                    System.out.println("Got connection, do some work.....");
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer.purge();
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No connection, re-trying in 5 seconds");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, 0, 5000);
```

Comment: A) That article is written for .NET, B) I don't think the arguments they bring up apply here.

Comment: @aioobe Updated the link.Even for Java i don't think Thread.sleep() is good practise

Comment: If this is a simple "5 second backoff" mechanism, I would say it doesn't really matter if the hardware interrupt granularity is 15ms or if `Thread.sleep` tends to "undersleep" a couple of milliseconds (which are basically the arguments that the article you link to brings up).